# Sqlite Query does not produce the correct result in android

Tags: android, sqlite

`SelectLogin` function returns the user whose password and phone equals to input password and phone.This query returns all users in the database.What is the problem?

```
public static ArrayList<User> selectLogin(String[] args){
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql=String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s =%s AND %s = %s;", TABLE_NAME,CLM_PASSWORD,args[0],CLM_PHONE,args[1]);
    Cursor cursor=Config.database.rawQuery(sql,args);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CLM_ID));
        String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CLM_PHONE));
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CLM_PASSWORD));

        users.add(new User(id,phone,password));
    }

    return users;
}
private ArrayList<User> checkLoign(){
    String[] args=new String[]{edtPassword.getText().toString(),edtPhone.getText().toString()};
    ArrayList<User> users;
    users=User.selectLogin(args);
        return users;
}
```

Comment: The docs say you shouldn't use ';' at the end.

Comment: Use `String.format()` for adding table name and field names. But use the arguments parameter of `rawQuery` for the where clause.
```Config.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM wherever WHERE formattedIn = ? AND alsoFormattedIn = ?", args);```